# CursorAdapter для ListView

Tags: android

Вытаскиваю из БД данные в коллекции и оттуда потом уже в ListView. Знаю что есть CursorAdapter, но не понимаю как их применить. Пожалуйста, распишите подробнее что нужно делать пошагово. На startandroid не очень понял как и что

Comment: Опишите [конкретнее](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), что именно вам не понятно, с примером кода. Никто тут не будет писать расширенные уроки для тех, кто не понял уроки на startandroid - здесь не обучающий ресурс, а для решения конкретных проблем. CursorAdapter работает, как не трудно догадаться из названия, с классом Cursor - никакого "вытаскивания" данных из БД в коллекции ему не требуется (вообще это довольно глупая затея, работаете с БД - работайте напрямую или пишите враппер какой-нибудь)